# Como traducir dspace JSPUI

Tags: html, repositorio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error interno del sistema

El sistema ha experimentado un error interno. Por favor, vuelva a intentarlo de nuevo, y si el problema persiste, por favor, contáctese con nosotros para poder arreglarlo.

`webui.supported.locales = en

```
<property name="acceptableFilenames">
        <list>
            <value>news-top.html</value>
            <value>news-side.html</value>
            <value>news-top_es.html</value>
            <value>news-side_es.html</value>
        </list>
    </property>`
```

no funcionan

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Cuando trato de traducir a español el DSPACE, sale la ventana que he subido no se muestras las noticias. como puedo solucionarlo ?